# Possible to have more than one redirect_uri?

Tags: asana, asana-connect

I would like to be able to redirect to a development environment in addition to the production environment. Is it possible to specify more than one redirect_uri? Specifically, I would like to be able to redirect to localhost.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi unfortunately does not currently support this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks - Any plans to support this in the future?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it anytime soon, but it is on the list of things to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like me, create several apps, one for each environment.